# Workflow with plastic scm in development cycle

Tags: plasticscm

I am trying to understand whether Plasticscm can allow the following workflow

1. After a developer has finished their work on a task view, he/she wants to submit it for review to the parent stream
2. Is it possible to generate a list of files pending for review by a particular developer? Ideally this list should be printed/stored in a file.
3. Assuming the review process accepted the changes in the main archive, an integrator test has to be performed using binaries produced from all accepted reviews at a particular day. Is it possible to generate such binaries from source versions that are not yet officially part of the archive?
4. Can an integrator user be the only one that can commit the changes to the archive with plastic SCM?

Thank you for all your time and effort. Excuse my ignorance.. I tried to browse the relevant documentation but could not find answers to the above questions.

Answer (score 2):

I'll try to answer although there're some points I'm not fully understanding (point number 3).

The "cm diff" command will give you a list of added, deleted, moved and changed items in the branch. The command output can be piped to a file.

If you have the integrator role in your company I do recommend you to use the code review functionality that is by default included in Plastic SCM.

Plastic SCM also has an integrated security system, so, you will be able to determine the users that are going to have merge permissions in certain branches.